# Sending message from one app to another app when both apps are in background in android

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a use case when I need to send a message at instant from one app which is in background to another app which is also in background.

The best thing I could use is BroadcastReceiver but for some reason it takes couple of seconds but I need to send the message at 100% reliable and with in milliseconds.

I tried with IntentService but it seems like android has some restrictions when starting intentservice when app that is starting the service is in the background, it gives unable to start service as app is in background.

I don't want to use foreground service as I am not doing any UI tasks and why should I use foreground when I am not doing anything on the UI.

I don't want to use AIDL as it seems to be overkill for a simple event that I want to send.

WorkManager can work within the app so I have not tried that.

Can someone suggest the best way to do this ?